# C. How to keep the value of a sum into an integer variable in a while loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I would like to ask for some help for this block of code. It is a basic idea of registering the values and quantities of itens while shopping. But each time a new item is bought, the value of the last one is lost. So I would like to ask how can I sum the values of diferent items while the shopping is not finished. Thanks a lot.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char cod;
    int value=1;
    int status=1;
    int quantity;
    int counter=1;
    
    while(status!=0){
        /*for(counter=1;counter<5;counter++);*/
        printf("Write the value of the product: ");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        printf("Write the quantity of the product: ");
        scanf("%d",&quantity);
        (value=value*quantity);
        printf("Total value is: R$ %d\n", value);
        printf("Write the operation code: ");
        scanf("%d",&status);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to store a total, it needs to be in a different variable than the one you are reading from the user, like "order_total".  If you want to keep a list of all items, a std::vector< one_item_structure > is one way to do that,  one_item_struct is going to be something like { value, quantity }

Comment: @DaveS: You appear to be confusing C with C++. The programming language C does not have a class `std::vector`.

Comment: initialize a running total to 0 out of the loop, add to it in the loop.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel - yes, I mostly work with C++ these days.  The idea is the same but it should be an array of struct not a std::vector of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking something like this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char cod;
  int value = 1;
  int status = 1;
  int quantity;
  int counter = 1;
  int total = 0;

  while (status != 0) {
    printf("Write the value of the product: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    printf("Write the quantity of the product: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantity);
    
    // Update the total here
    total += (value * quantity);
    printf("Total value is: R$ %d\n", total);

    printf("Write the operation code: ");
    scanf("%d", &status);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This just keeps a `total` variable and for each loop it adds the current total with the new `value * quantity` from the input asked.

You just want to make sure you don't overflow/underflow.

Comment: thanks a lot! Now the looping is working with the variable the way it needs to be